# JSON deserialize array with custom objects in it

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json-deserialization

Hi this is my JSON file I would like to parse in C#:

```
 {
  "modelParam": {
    "defaultConfigFilePath": "../modelParam.json",
    "actionType":[
            {
            "showText": 
                {
                    "feld": "input" , 
                    "text": "Port",
                    "value": 4 
                }
            },
            {
            "showText": 
                {
                    "feld": "input" , 
                    "text": "TestTest",
                    "value": 78  
                }
            }
        ]
    }
  }
```

Does anyone have an idea how to parse/deserialize this file?

Best regards
C.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create this c# classes.

```
   public class Model
{
    public Modelparam modelParam { get; set; }
}

public class Modelparam
{
    public string defaultConfigFilePath { get; set; }
    public Actiontype[] actionType { get; set; }
}

public class Actiontype
{
    public Showtext showText { get; set; }
}

public class Showtext
{
    public string feld { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

After that you can deserialize(parse) it to c# object. For this:

```
var model =System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model>("your json source");
```